# mean of multiple rows (points) in matlab

Tags: matlab, mean

I have a matrix named data with x,y,z positions.
I have calculated the distance between all the points using pdist and got the matrix 'out' which has the diff of x, diff of y and diff of z and their corresponding rows.

```
A= data;
D1= pdist(A(:,1));
D2= pdist(A(:,2));
D3= pdist(A(:,3));
D = [D1' D2' D3'];


tmp = ones(size(A,1));
tmp = tril(tmp,-1);
[rowIdx,colIdx ] = find(tmp);
out = [D,A(rowIdx,:),A(colIdx,:)];
```

I want to calculate the average of all those points which satisfies certain conditions:
diff z <7 and diff x and diff y < 4.

So I wrote the following code:

```
a= find (out(:,3)>0);
cal=out(a,:);
b= cal(:,3)<7;
cal2 = cal(b,:);

[s,k]= size (cal2);


for i=1:s

    if (cal2(i,1) < 4) && (cal2(i,2) < 4);

        xmean = mean (cal2(i,[4,7]));
        ymean = mean (cal2(i,[5,8]));
        zmean = mean (cal2(i,[6,9]));
        fd = [xmean ymean zmean];


    end
end
```

The problem is, with this code I can get the mean of two points at a time. So, my output is giving me more number of points than what I actually want.I want to get the mean off all the points which satisfies the condition.

My final goal is to get a list of points where I can get the points whose (diff z is > 7 )+ (the mean of the points whose diff z is <7 while diff x < 4 and diff y <4) + (diff z < 7 but diff x and diff y > 4).

Can someone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by points with diff z < 7?  The difference from each point to each point is calculated. so each point has differences z (multiples). Do you mean each point with at least one diff z < 7 ? or do you mean each point with all diff < 7?

Comment: @Steffen: For all those points whose z value difference is <7. i.e.  for all those points where out(:,3) <7

Comment: assume you have z-values [1,5,10]. There you mean only point 5? assume you have z-valzes[1,2,3,4,5,100]. There you mean none? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: If I have x,y,z (10 23 3), (12 24 5), (2 25 10). Then I want two points in the output 1. mean of (10 23 3) and (12 24 5) [since diff z is 2 which is <7] and 2. (2 25 10) [diff z is > 7]. Note: diff z of last two points is 5 but we won't consider that because the other conditions: diff x<4 and diff y< 4 is not satisfied @Steffen

Comment: Ok. Made that a bit clearer. Assume you have (x,y,z) p1=(0,0,0), p2=(0,0,5), p3=(0,0,10). diff x is good so concentrate on z. diff(p1,p2) is 5. So use both points. diff(p2,p3) is 5. So use p2 and p3. diff(p1,p3) is 10. So do not use p1 and p3. --- What do you expect to get as mean value?: a) mean(p1,p2,p3); or b) mean(p2) or c) mean(p1,p2,p2,p3)

Comment: @Steffen In that case, I'll go for c)

Answer (score 0):

Say you want the mean of all points where diffZ<7, diffX<4 and diffY<4. Assuming that `out` stores the corresponding differences in x,y,z in the first three columns, and point coordinates in columns 4-9.

```
%# this is true for all points you want to average
condition = out(:,1) > 4 & out(:,2) > 4 & out(:,3) < 7;

%# get coordinates satisfying the condition; create a 2n-by-3 array
coords = [out(condition, 4:6);out(condition, 7:9)];

%# if you don't want to count coordinates multiple times when taking the average, run 
%# coords = unique(coords,'rows');

%# average
meanCoordinates = mean(coords,1);
```

Comment: Thanks . I could not find a better way to store the points. I indeed faced problem using unique. Is there some other way to store them? Right now column 4,5 and 6 are x1, y1, z1 and column 7, 8, 9 are x2, y2, z2. How should I implement 'pointIndices = out(condition,4:5);' ? Please help @Jonas

Comment: Also, I am getting the following error using the above code: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. Error in meanCoordinates = mean(A(pointIndices,1); @Jonas

Comment: @nabaneetamukhopadhyay: see my edit. Instead of storing the points coordinates in `out`, you can store `rowIdx`, and `colIdx`, and use these to index into your coordinate array `A`. However, this is only really necessary if (1) you want only the mean of unique points, and (2) it is possible that multiple points in `A` have identical coordinates.

Comment: If I run 'coords = [out(condition, 4:6);out(condition, 7:9)];' , it returns me the data set I started with. I have edited my question and provided my initial data. Also, I clarified my exact problem in the comment to the other answer. Can you please help? @Jonas

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [0,0,0;0,0,5;0,0,10];

% create matrices with the distances 
% [p1-p1, p1-p2, p1-p3;
%  p2-p1, p2-p2, p2-p3;
%  p3-p1, p3-p2, p3-p3];
dx= squareform(pdist(A(:,1)));
dy= squareform(pdist(A(:,2)));
dz= squareform(pdist(A(:,3)));
% dz = [0,5,10;5,0,5;10,5,0];

% select all points stisfying condition
idx = dx < 4 & dy < 4 & dz < 7;
% remove entries of the main diagonal
idx(sub2ind(size(idx),1:size(A,1),1:size(A,1))) = 0;
% select all indices. Since all distances are 2 times in the full matrix,
% only r or c is needed
[r,c] = find(idx==1);
% r = [2,1,3,2]; c = [1,2,2,3]

meanOfPoints = mean(A(r,:))
```

Comment: I tried it on my data set. It is returning only one point as answer. I have edited my question and provided my data set. I have taken the x y values for each z and I got some repeating x,y values (not unique values but nearby i.e diff x and diff y <4). Not all the x,y values are repeating. I am considering that those which are repeating within diff z<7 can be merged to their average position. Rest of the points are unique and should be listed as it is. I hope I am sounding clear. Can you please help? @Steffen